# Simplest and best way to display a list of items on Windows Form application using C#

Tags: c#

At my school I was handed a project for my C# course. It's a fairly simple project but I don't know how to go about doing it or even start doing it. So I'll just get to it then.

> I am supposedly a developer hired by a book company that needs a developer to code an application for them to work on one machine in the work place.
>
> Users should be able to do the following with the application:
>
> - View a list of books, as well as a list of Audio publications
> - Create new records for books and audio
>
> The application should adhere to the following specifications:
>
> - It must be windows form
> - It must be user friendly and easy to navigate
> - Data should be saved to a file when application closes and be read back into it when it opens
> - It must perform appropriate input validation
> - It must be well designed and support future changes and the business is growing
>
> The following data needs to be stored about the publications:
>
> Book:
>
> - Publish date
> - Title
> - Author
> - ISBN number
> - Type of book (enum)
> - Type of over (enum)
>
> Audio:
>
> - Publish date
> - Title
> - Artist
> - Number of tracks
> - total length
> - Type of audio (enum)

I need to make use of object-orientated programming concepts such as classes, properties, methodes, inheritance and polymorphism.

Basically what I need to know is how should I display the information on the form and what is the best way to create new records of that info and what format to save it in.

We haven't learnt anything about grids, so I doubt it's that. We have only learnt how to read/write from text files. Also I suspect that I need to create a class for all the publications and create two child classes for the Book and Audio in order to handle the data that is different between them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. This question is way too broad. You'll need a tutorial, some you might find on the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info). Come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: `I don't know how to go about doing it or even start doing it` you said what you learned at the bottom, so start by creating a text file to store the data in question and creating the functionality to create new books to it and read all the books from it. This will be pretty much 90% of your project(and doesn't really require a winform for testing/developing) the rest is just making it look pretty with perhaps a listbox or listview depends on what you have learned towards that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to go on programming with C# :)

This application is more simple than it looks at first sight, you just need to split the requirements in smaller parts and start doing.

I'll show you how I would do it:

**1. Create classes of type `Book` and `Audio` with the fields you've listed above:** this will be useful to store and list the information. You will probably need methods and/or properties to retrieve this information.

**2. Use a `List<Book>` and a `List<Audio>` to store the publications that will be read from the text files**: I'm supposing that you will take the list of Audio and Books from there, that's why you've been taught how to read `txt` files :) 
Here you can find how to use [`List<T>`](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=list%3CT%3E%20c%23) objects.

**3. Display the information in a grid:** you can create a `Grid` and add to it columns and rows to display what you've read in the `txt` file. For doin' that, you will need to loop through the `List<T>` and retrieving its field values. I let you documentation of the [`Grid`](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=grid%20class%20c%23) class.

**4. Create a form for creating new records:** In this form you will need to add controls such as `Drop-down lists`(for `Enum` fields for example) or `Text-Boxes`. You will have to check if all the fields are filled and then write their values in a `txt` file to store the new records.

You have also to take into account how the design of this application will be. As your teacher has asked for, it has to be user-friendly and easy to navigate.

I let a kind of [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx) to give you something to start from :)

Comment: I have two questions about the advice you have given me.
1. Do you recommend me making 1 text file or 2 for the publications and in what way is the best way to format the text for easy reading/writing.
2. In the 4th step you state that I should write the entry from the form directly to the text file. But in the instructions it explicitly tells me that I should only save to a text file when the application closes. Does this mean I just create a new object for the entry and add it to the list. And save that list to the text file?

Comment: 1. Depends on where you take the publications from... I mean, are you given any text file or do you have to make your own `txt` files? Commonly, the client or, in you case, the teacher gives a `txt` to be read the first time the app is run, and then, if you want to keep more entries (for example, if the user is allowed to add new ones) you can write in another one handled by the code OR IN THE SAME, but that depends on if you have writing privileges... so, summarizing, if you have your own `txt` file, use just one, if the file with the entries is already made, use 2.

Comment: I would use a line for each publication and the fields separated with blank spaces. 2. Well, if so, you can add the entry to the `List` first, and call an event when the user wants to close the application and then save it to the file.

Comment: @Dean White I am not sure why you are using a txt file to store data Have you considered a SQLite Database it is 10 times easier to work with the data and the User Interface can be highly flexible Reach out if you want some help FREE no scam C# and VB.Net are my hobbies I can share link to small apps on GitHub

Answer (score 6):

Use a DataGridView along with a DataTable.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Publish", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Author", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Book A", DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016"), "Author A"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Book B", DateTime.Parse("1/2/2016"), "Author B"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Book C", DateTime.Parse("1/3/2016"), "Author C"});

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```